# Autolayout and UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, nslayoutconstraint

I created a panel with some subviews in it and used a `NSLayoutConstraint`s to achieve positioning.

I would then display it in a `UIPopoverController`. Before setting it, I would call `[UIView layoutIfNeeded]` command to force it to size itself (the overall size is based on the size of an image in it that can be different sizes).

```
PhotoDisplayPanel *panel = [[PhotoDisplayPanel alloc] initWithPhoto:cell.photo isAddPhoto:cell.isAddPhoto];

DLog(@"BEFORE | panel.frame: %@", panel);

[self.view addSubview:panel];

DLog(@"MIDDLE | panel.frame: %@", panel);

[panel layoutIfNeeded];

DLog(@"AFTER | panel.frame: %@", panel);
```

log:

```
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController viewDidLoad] | BEFORE | panel.frame: <PhotoDisplayPanel: 0x7878a3f0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7878a7e0>>
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController viewDidLoad] | MIDDLE | panel.frame: <PhotoDisplayPanel: 0x7878a3f0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7878a7e0>>
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController viewDidLoad] | AFTER | panel.frame: <PhotoDisplayPanel: 0x7878a3f0; frame = (-358 -245; 578 289); layer = <CALayer: 0x7878a7e0>>
```

Previously, I would add the `[panel layoutIfNeeded]` call before adding it to a view. This worked fine. But with iOS 8.1, they changed how `layoutIfNeeded` works and if you call it before adding my panel to a view, it freaks out and starts breaking constraints to make it work properly.

My issue is that working with a `UIPopoverController`, since I can not call `layoutIfNeeded` my panel has no size, so it uses the popover's default size:

[image]

While the panel looks like:

[image]

I create the `UIPopoverController`, set the panel as its view, and then set the `preferedContentSize` property to the panel's size:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController.view = self.currentPanel;
viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.currentPanel.frame.size.width, self.currentPanel.frame.size.height + 00);
```

Since the panel has not been sized, it is (0, 0).

My question is now, how can I force my panel to size itself based on the constraints?

Answer (score 17):

The solution is to calculate the preferredContentSize based on your constraints.
Note : Your constraints have to be pinned (left/top/right/bottom) to the view controller view in order to be able to calculate the total width/height of the view.

The way to do it, add these lines in your viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

CGSize resultSize = [self.view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
self.preferredContentSize = resultSize;
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. I tested it and it works beautifully.

Comment: In Swift this is `self.preferredContentSize = self.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)`

Comment: Note when @Tanguy says "your constraints have to be pinned to the view controller view" be sure your widest UI element has e.g. a trailing anchor constraint relative to the view and your bottom most UI element has e.g. a bottom anchor constraint relative to the view, for example: `widestItem.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)` and `view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomMostItem.bottomAnchor, constant: 16)`

Answer (score 0):

Swift version 4/5 of Tanguy G.'s working answer:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let resultSize = view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
    self.preferredContentSize = resultSize
}
```